# Как работать с curl php

Tags: php, curl, php5

Дал мне работодатель задание, а конкретно что от меня требуется не пойму (с PHP дружу). Что нужно сделать конкретней как для новичка, или напишите ответ и куда копать?

Вот само задание:

Создать файл с помощью которого мы сможем отправлять cURL запросы. Должен уметь направлять по GET, так и POST (form submit). Также обязательно должна быть возможность передачи пользовательских cookie и session. Должна быть реализована возможность варьирования, через GET параметры, например:

http://yoursite.com/curl.php?method=...5r435435frefwe
направляет GET запрос (не отправка формы) на гугл, с куками 5r435435frefwe

http://yoursite.com/curl.php?method=...okie=user_data
направляет POST на meta.ua данным формы, куки юзера

Также создайте страницу, примеру enter.php куда будете присылать ваш запрос, и продемонстрируйте различные способы работы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерный код вашего curl.php

```
$method = $_POST['method'];
$site = $_POST['site'];
$params = http_build_query($_POST);

$ch = curl_init();


if ($method === 'POST') {
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$site);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);
} else {
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$site . '?' . $params);
}

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не подскажите ли вы сайт по curl чтобы более детально с ним розобратся. (Понимаю всьо кроме 3 строчки)

Comment: http://myblaze.ru/urok-20-rabota-s-curl-v-php/